Having a singular ERC-20 address across multiple blockchains
For the sake of maintaining a singular smart contract address across different EVM compatible block chains, is it generally safe to use Nick's method to deploy ERC20 contracts.
My goal here is deploy the wrapped version of native token for a particular subnet on Avalanche across other block chains the subnet will communicate with.

You need to verify all Avalanche subnets use a similar method to generate addresses.
The best way to do this is to contact the dev support of each subnet, or you just try it out.
